# Arrangement of the layout is like trembling till the result/weather forecast for new town is loaded in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout

I use conditional rendering for my weather app on github.The app is functioning fine, but when it renders a result for a newly entered town, the arrangement of the layout is like trembling till the result/weather forecast for new town is loaded. I suppose this is a design question. Can someone check? 
Here is my app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Spinner from '../UI/Spinner';
import './App.css';
import {TweenLite, TimelineLite} from "gsap/TweenMax";

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        cityData: null,
        cityName: '',
        confirmedCityName: '',
        error: '',
        searchNameString: '',
        woeid: '',
        weatherData: '',
        weatherForecast: '',
        weatherIcon: null,
        loading: false
    }

    validate = () => {
        let isError = false;
        let error = '';

        if(this.state.cityName.length === 0){
              isError = true;
              error = 'Pls.enter a valid city name';
          } else {
              error = ''
          }
          this.setState({
            error,
            confirmedCityName: '',
          })
          return isError
    }

    submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const err = this.validate();

        if(err === false) {
            const searchString = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=';
            const searchNameString = searchString.concat(this.state.cityName);
            this.setState({
                searchNameString
            })
            fetch(searchNameString)
                .then(response =>  {
                  console.log(response);
                  return response.json()
                })
                .then(data => {
                    if(data.length === 0) {
                        let error = 'You have entered invalid city name or name that not exist in our database of cities, pls.enter existent city name';
                        this.setState({
                            error,
                            confirmedCityName: ''
                        }) 
                    } else {
                        const woeid = data[0].woeid;
                        this.setState({
                            loading: true,
                            confirmedCityName: this.state.cityName,
                            cityData: data,
                            woeid
                        })
                        const searchString = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/';
                        const searchWoeidString = searchString.concat(`${this.state.woeid}/`);
                        return fetch(searchWoeidString)
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    return response.json()
                    }              
                )
                .then(data => {
                    const today = data.consolidated_weather[0];
                    const country = data.parent.title;
                    const weatherForecast = 
                    <div>Today in <strong>{this.state.cityName}, {country}</strong> weather will be with <strong>{today.weather_state_name}</strong>, 
                        min temperature <strong>{parseInt(today.min_temp)}°C</strong>,  
                        max temperature <strong>{parseInt(today.max_temp)}°C</strong>,
                        and humidity will be <strong>{today.humidity}%</strong></div>;
                    const weatherIcon = `https://www.metaweather.com/static/img/weather/png/${today.weather_state_abbr}.png`;                    
                    this.setState({
                        loading: false, 
                        weatherData: data,
                        weatherForecast,
                        weatherIcon,
                        cityName: ''
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error));

                this.setState({
                    weatherData: '',
                    weatherForecast: '',
                })
        }
    }

    nameChangeHandler = input => event => {
        this.setState({
          [input]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let animation = new TimelineLite();
        TweenLite.ticker.useRAF(false);
        TweenLite.lagSmoothing(0);

        const spinningPic = document.getElementById('spinning-pic');
        animation.to(spinningPic, 1, {rotation: "+=360", transformOrigin:"center center"});
    }

    render() {
        let weatherOutput = null;
        if(this.state.loading) {
            weatherOutput = (
                <React.Fragment>
                    {/*Spinner*/}
                    <Spinner />
                    {/*Content-forecast-empty*/}
                    <div className="container-fluid content-forecast">
                          <div className="container"> 
                              <p className="forecast"></p>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        } else {
            weatherOutput = (
              <React.Fragment>
                  {/*Weather Icon got from server*/}
                  <div className={"container-fluid content" + (this.state.weatherIcon !== null ? ' visible' : ' nonvisible')}>
                      <div className="container"> 
                          <div className="img-wrapper"><img src={this.state.weatherIcon} alt=""/></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  {/*Forecast string empty*/}
                  <div className="container-fluid content-forecast">
                      <div className="container"> 
                          <div className="forecast">{this.state.weatherForecast}</div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </React.Fragment>
            )
        }
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="container-fluid title-background">
                    <div className="container">
                        <h1>Weather forecast app</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="container-fluid header-background">
                    <div className="container">
                        <h3>Search Weather data for {this.state.confirmedCityName}</h3>
                        <form>
                          <input 
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="Pls.enter city name"
                              value={this.state.cityName}
                              onChange={this.nameChangeHandler('cityName')}
                          />
                          <button
                              type="submit"
                              onClick={this.submitHandler}
                          >
                              ENTER
                          </button>
                        </form>
                        <p className="error-message">{this.state.error}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    {/*Opening pic*/}  
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="spinning-pic-wrapper"><img id="spinning-pic" src="https://www.metaweather.com/static/img/weather/png/c.png" 
                        className={(this.state.weatherIcon !== null || this.state.loading === true ? 'nonVisible' : '')} alt="sun"/></div>  
                    </div>
                    {/*Weather Icon got from server, Forecast string empty*/}
                    <div className="weatherOutputWrapper">
                      {weatherOutput} 
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div className="container-fluid footer-background">
                    <div className="container">
                        <h3>Getting today's weather forecast</h3>
                        <div className="icon-wrapper"><img src="https://www.metaweather.com/static/img/weather/lc.svg" alt="weather Icon"/></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

An here is the css file:

```
/* ------------------------------------ */
input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

/* ------------------------------------ */
button {
    outline: none;
    border: solid 2px #fff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out, border .3s ease-in-out;
}

button:hover, button:focus {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #00697D;
    border: solid 2px transparent;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 450px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    font-family: OswaldLight;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

form {
    text-align: center;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.container {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.title-background {
    background-color: #353432;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}

.title-background h1 {
    color: #fff;
}

.header-background {
    background-color: #4E4D4A;
}

.header-background h3 {
    font-size: 35px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4E4D4A;
    color: #FF8C18;
}

.header-background p {
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

.content-forecast {
    height: 45px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    text-align: center;
}

.weather-forecast {
    background-color: #4E4D4A;
}

.error-message {
    color: #ecf0f1;
    height: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.spinning-pic-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

#spinningPic {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.nonVisible {
    display: none;
}

.visible {
    display: block;
}

.footer-background {
    background-color: #353432;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    font-family: OswaldLight;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

.footer-background h3 {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.icon-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

.icon-wrapper img{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You are storing ReactElement in a state property and this is a very bad practice. You should store in state the data you need to render your ReactElement.

Comment: @Kornflexx I didn't understand can you explain pls.

Comment: Your weatherForecast state property is a ReactElement (jsx declaration).

Comment: You Component is really big, it will help you to split him in more simple component. If you thinks you have an issue with render, try to console.log in each render to see if you have the correct amount of expected render for an action.

Comment: @Kornflexx weather Forecast I can transform it in template literal, in order not to be an jsx element